# PyQT from Source: The following modules are not being compiled in this configuration

Tags: visual-studio, qt, pyqt, msbuild, pyqt5

I'm trying to compile PyQT5 but I need to include these modules, does anyone have any ideas on how to reconfigure to include these modules?

```
cd E:\QT\5.15.2\Src\qtwebengine

E:\QT\5.15.2\Src\qtwebengine>E:\QT\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake WEBENGINE_CONFIG+=use_proprietary_codecs
```

Output log:

```
Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Qt WebEngine Build Tools:
  Use System Ninja ....................... yes
  Use System Gn .......................... no
  Jumbo Build Merge Limit ................ no
  Developer build ........................ no
  Sanitizer .............................. no

Note: The following modules are not being compiled in this configuration:
    webenginecore
    webengine
    webenginewidgets
    pdf
    pdfwidgets

WARNING: Python version 2 (2.7.5 or later) is required to build QtWebengine.

WARNING: Python version 2 (2.7.5 or later) is required to build QtPdf.

WARNING: QtWebEngine will not be built.

WARNING: QtPdf will not be built.

Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'nmake'.
Once everything is built, you must run 'nmake install'.
Qt will be installed into 'E:\QT\5.15.2\msvc2019_64'.

Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
the previous build.
```

Comment: Hi, what is the app type on your side?

Comment: QWebEngineView, I need to compile this version of pyqt5 with codecs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove from Windows env other installations of python 3 and leave only 2.7 , than delete the build dir completely. After changes are made, the saved cache is not updated (bug), so it needs to be deleted. [Reference](https://forum.qt.io/post/756005)